# Scroll only on scrollbar's thumb touch in Android

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I am using a HorizontalScrollView and I want to allow the user to scroll 
 only when the user taps on the scrollbar's thumb or on the track. I don't want to allow scrolling when users taps inside the view.

The reason for this, is because inside the the ScrollView there is a FrameLayout for painting purposes and if scrolling is enabled inside the view, the user can't use painting functions and the view gets scrolled.

Comment: You could intercept the scrolling events at your frameLayout element level. You will need to write a CustomFrameLayout extends FrameLayout that overrides the interceptevent methods. Interception of events is a delicate issue but there is much documentation about it you can Google for.